# How to test for magnesium and calcium oxide?

Tags: elemental-analysis

Is there a way to test for $\ce{MgO}$ and $\ce{CaO}$?

I want to prove that  $\ce{MgO}$ and $\ce{CaO}$ are created from their respective calcinations.

$$\ce{MgCO3 (s)->[heat] MgO(s) + CO2(g)}$$

$$\ce{CaCO3 (s)->[heat] CaO(s) + CO2(g)}$$

Comment: For iron clad proof!?! Use $200,000 x-ray diffractometer.

Comment: I assume these are 2 separate solutions, one with MgCO3 and one with the CaCO3, and not a single mixture of the two?  Or do I have that wrong?

Comment: @airhuff - ?!? the (s) in the chemical equations means solids not solutions.

Comment: @MaxW, brain-skip on my part, slipped right by me, thx.  My first thought for a quick and dirty test is to heat the salts under an inert gas stream, measure the CO2 coming off by whatever means, then weigh the remaining solid and see if it all adds up.  If you really want to be sure, digest the solid, dilute like crazy, and measure by Mg or Ca ICP-AES or AA!

Comment: "Proof" is the kicker. You can't analyze $\ce{CO3^{2-}}$ by either ICP-AES (\$200K instrument too?) or AA (\$50K instrument?). A simple flame test would show difference between Ca and Mg but is that "proof?"

Comment: @MaxW, yes, proof is by degrees.  And I said to measure the Mg and Ca by ICP or AA. The liberated $\ce{CO2}$ (g means gas here ;) would simply be measured by any number of classical techniques (titration in _cheap_ $\ce{CO2}$ coulometer, IR detector, adsorb and weigh, etc.).  You could also measure the oxygen in the (undigested) solid by classical pyrolytic Mertz oxygen analysis (~35$ analysis), though the latter could have a 10% + relative uncertainty in this matrix.

Comment: Hi - [please don't use MathJax in titles on chem.SE](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/149), thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Magnesium oxide and calcium oxide can be easily differentiable by its reaction with water. The former is practically insoluble in water(0.0086 g/100 mL (30 °C)), hence magnesium hydroxide will be formed in negligible amount. However, the latter is soluble in water and will form forms calcium hydroxide to a large extent.

You can also differentiate them [by forming their sulfates and testing their solubility.](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/167916/17368)

There are selective test like ammonium oxalate test (more details [here](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ja01397a016)) and $\ce{Na2HPO4}$ test (more details [here](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/778417/1-s2.0-S0021925818X90358/1-s2.0-S0021925818915759/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEIf%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJIMEYCIQCs%2FD5Eb4dg1He%2BJUikZk56OupZtuhti8MyTBKaN9sq2gIhAMfhPMv9N0HHLdiLicizJGQqpIVGbRnGyQQwVJCNVZZZKtUECPD%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEQBRoMMDU5MDAzNTQ2ODY1IgxsUAPtKBZdjpuTcpwqqQS9XgpGWGps5S6gY88OjGmh9ICTpnjhfrucEm2PT5wSxox5T5UNvzmoyKapWseKjQYOXFi6wE%2BTpf91GxC7MkXggfReX7FghyvAxP2YntBDXQM1z0HdPACYKGTvo4OBWt0yWNsLaS%2BOuOak%2BKljf45VLt9O8EcgP5%2BQsZydkz8sAJgMdZdJ6AD7rKEHQj8mJOdIlfra1OQy%2FdYKip%2F0yJb0ceqkb2YeRK14GC0ygaBjm2j2AEa4nTgljX%2FDAP2N71fF6KKunXFzjyDC5rRtbGp2p5p8f28iA2FoYlJ5mS7JDAyjkY1Dt6U1YN7ys0A2QcIYCX2%2F%2FujH%2FiOQAP7mePtuup0uMhhV3MGAaEca3qmQT8OWU77LPJkcE5O%2F4N9k2RmestycgIWg3I%2FRWQ5SewtnzND4VsMQ1RtXSJXOpTvVXJ85SZ75F0LfjBHfQIFjF2FryDuYb%2FsNM6CTRTqvFkn%2BBvpwB6hyRPVFXZJmRBoRSJCL89ud32hPUnB%2Bkv2iVWoYNohOMnSlcL6HvwVXkVM3JZTwLih6WHoXht8dl4BIkcloQfeTG16C3PxU5gUWRrAvCX1c6SE4ueLRreL5gNnKg0SVylyUUxAi%2FNUyuR47ni5SEc%2BS5UA2xLUbJyeo4AAzl%2BrxbE4aDqjfp5eyBYGmeRR9EMppuD0yQaDjRvqEVbpbkjG78PsoZ7OP3PDQtrlUCUkZGXN8F9YFQ5sjc794cebpfUgpjqR1MOLdv54GOqgBpgI42VL43f8Du4VM4S0TvDkXfuRTr%2BFfm8Qiuk%2FanEbqxiea4dDL2nrEtCTJle7%2BBzuLiqnm5A0N7UIwvkXjNyGgCWh0DTMYqejrGXpPpLOnibP69MpS1MqdCbmbGdEra3rxN%2FNmBV87GB869fxVw9U2WHA1yHR5SDrFb3qzwQ5pxFaLx9y2qZf9Qh5b9mf09nGoHrFjgyO6MehhZPOFvp6mCIXJTIcT&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20230124T154428Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTY6R2HITNE%2F20230124%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=230a499d3292384355dbc814acff4143ddeb8c70469cb5ee334e4bfadf9176a7&hash=e308b3da23c569e41708e22ec6f70596ed32fd5785e6a13d2d7d8b30086e00c4&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0021925818915759&tid=spdf-53f58948-3cfb-42e9-b009-803d36c4dba8&sid=8d0422561619f54feb7aa7c7c9e80bdf198fgxrqb&type=client&tsoh=d3d3LnNjaWVuY2VkaXJlY3QuY29t&ua=070b585e0b570a5602&rr=78e9e3ffbe7685e5&cc=in)) which is described [in the other answers to this question.](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/51653/how-to-separate-and-analyse-a-sample-of-cations-of-alkaline-and-earth-alkaline-c/52051) The best test however is Flame test (also described in the other question).